# select audio file from database

Tags: java, mysql, audio, blob

I have used blob datatype for storing image in database. Now, i am trying the same operation for the audio file. Storing audio file into database and trying to retrieve it from the database. I have successfully inserted the audio file into database, and i'm trying to retrieve it back. But, i don't know what to write here, as i have used `response.setContentType("image/jpg");`for retrieving image. Can anybody help me, how to retrieve audio file from database.. I will very much appreciate.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of MIME types here. Your type of audio file is probably there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type

Comment: can you tell me how to retrieve audio file from database. I used the above link, but unable to retrieve.

Comment: response.setContentType("image/jpg") doesn't retrieve an image from a database. It sets the HTTP Content-Type header in your applications response. You should look elsewhere in the code for a SELECT statement for the image and try and mimic that. However, it sounds like your missing some basic knowledge.